# Should I try to "hide" the Model and ViewModel from the View?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my Wpf project I try to seperate the view and the view-model.
I was thinking that e.g. the data-contract between view-model and model should be hidden from the view.

In practice however quite often you want to display a simple property from the data-contract in the view, which is not possible without a reference to the data-contract in the view.

E.g.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Group = basedata.Groups.CurrentItem.Code;
```

requires a reference to the type of `CurrentItem`.

I could also expose a string property in the view-model like

```
public string CurrentGroupCode { get { return Groups.CurrentItem.Code; } }
```

This also looks so overdone. I tend to use the reference, because it results in less code.
Any objections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I would go with your option 2. Why? Well if you want to implement the notification mechanism via `INotifyPropertyChanged`, this is the easiest way. If you want to pass values from model to the view and vice versa your example would look like this.

```cs
public SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase // assuming that you have a base class for this
{
    public string CurrentGroupCode
    {
        get { return Groups.CurrentItem.Code; }
        set
        {
             Groups.CurrentItem.Code = value;          // assuming that the VM has been intialized correctly
             RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentGroupCode"); // implemented in base class
        }
    }

    /*
     * ...Initialization, logic a.s.o.
     */
}
```

Means, if the business logic, which should also be implemented at the VM layer, modifies such a property, the view will be notified and updated automatically. Additionally, the modification will be propagated automatically to the model, too.

You see, with this approach you're not only hiding the model from the view, you're also providing a good modularity on the VM level, since the other VMs don't need to know something of the model structure.

Comment: Fair enough. However my databinding with `Groups.CurrentItem` is already up-and running (with notify and such) in a generic way all good. So it's just about this one property `Code` as a kind of minor detail.